# Empty CGI.REDIRECT_URL on ColdFusion 2016

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I'm in the process of moving a site to ColdFusion 2016 on Linux/Apache, but one issue we have is the `CGI.REDIRECT_URL` value is empty. I checked and the following was in the `/etc/apache2/mod_jk.conf` file:

```
JkEnvVar REDIRECT_URL
```

It exists, but it's empty.

I couldn't find much on the web to help except [this article](https://www.hostmedia.co.uk/client/knowledgebase/201204236/Missing-CGI-variables.html), but its already setup like that. Vivio thought 2016 had the `redirect_url` in the request scope, but that's empty as well.

Comment: Are you dumping `cgi` or are you referencing `cgi.REDIRECT_URL` directly?  Dumping the `cgi` scope will only list a defined set of keys. https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2545-dumping-out-the-cgi-scope-does-not-list-all-available-cgi-values-in-coldfusion.htm

Comment: @user9263373 using it directly

Comment: Hmm, are you sure when you say _"it exists, but its empty"_?  Just because you `<cfoutput>'#cgi.REDIRECT_URL#'</cfoutput>` doesn't necessarily mean it exists.  The weird thing about the cgi scope is you can `<cfoutput>'#cgi.THIS_IS_A_FAKE_KEY#'</cfoutput>` and it won't throw an error and will display as empty.  The way to verify is by`structKeyExists( CGI, 'REDIRECT_URL' )`.

Comment: @user9263373 wow, i didn't know that! you're right, i just tested and it doesn't exist. but i found a workaround - or maybe this how it just works in cf2016 - instead of using CGI.REDIRECT_URL i used CGI.SCRIPT_NAME

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird that the cgi scope works that way.  Glad you found a workaround!

Comment: @user9263373 yeah thats definitely weird! thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should write up the solution as an answer to your problem.

Comment: @JamesAMohler actually, I did write up a nice summary of this as an answer, but decided to delete it since it technically didn't answer the question and figured it'd get dinged with downvotes.  Instead I posted my _"answer"_ as a separate question.

Comment: If it explains how you solved this problem, and how you discovered the solution, I would consider it to be a good answer. It could help out the next person.